# Index of elements

Tags: matlab

I have the following `for-loop` part of a function:

```
for i=1:5
for j=1:2
m=x(i)-c(j);
end
end
```

As a call to the function which includes the code above, I pass `two` values for `c`. Say the values passed are `(3,5)` for `c1` and `c2` respectively.

As you see in the `for-loop` above, I will have a two values for `c`, nanely, `c(1)` and `c(2)`.

For the `3` and `5` values I have above, how can I assign them to `c(1)` and `c(2)` respectively?

When I did the following for instance:

```
c(1)=center1;
c(2)=center2;
```

where `center1` and `center2` represent the passed value to the function, I got the following error:

```
In an assignment  A(I) = B, the number of elements in B and I must be
the same.

Error in functionName (line 32)
    c(1)=center1;
```

Answer (score 2):

It looks like `center1` is not a scalar. Print out the value or use [`isscalar`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/isscalar.html) to check it. This works:

```
c(1) = 1;
```

but this will not:

```
c(1) = [1 2];
```

Also, your double `for` loop makes no sense because you're overwriting the value of `m` on each iteration. Presumably you have more stuff inside it. However, you could just create a matrix `m` without any `for` loop at all using [`bsxfun`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html):

```
x = rand(1,5);
c = rand(1,2);
m = bsxfun(@minus,x(:),c(:).')
```

This results in `m` being a 5-by-2 matrix. You can use `bsxfun(@minus,x(:).',c(:))` if you prefer a 2-by-5 matrix.